# How can I get 18.10 Yaru icons in 19.04?

Tags: icons, 19.04

I quite like the 'squircle' icons in 18.10. All the posts I can find refer to changing the icon of a single file or folder. Is there a way to change the entire icon set in 19.04? Thanks.

Comment: get the icon set from ubuntu pacakges.. then copy the Yaru icon set folder in  `.icons` folder or `usr/share/icons` and choose the icon theme from `gnome-tweaks`..

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/all/yaru-theme-icon/filelist